# setting up page number for jqgrid

Tags: dynamic, jqgrid, pager

I am facing a problem in setting up the page numbers of jqgrid dynamically. I am new to this jqgrid and would like the assistance to learn it fast.

I have a scenario which if somebody can answer would be very great for me.

1. I have an application, which can bring millions of records in a single query output.
2. For this i want something like paging chunks of data instead of getting all data at once (which will not happen anyhow)
3. For this, i would hit server for first time and find out the total records to be displayed, but return only 2000 of it.
4. Once user uses paging next button and reaches the last record, on click of next button, the next 2000 records from server will be brought up.
5. Problem here is the pager shows that there are only 20 pages (i have set 100 as total records in a page), and it disable next button as soon as page 20 is accessed, thus stopping to get new set of data from server
6. Even if somehow, i get the next set of data, the page should shows me only 20 records of initial. I want page to show me total records/size of page in first go itself although there will be only 2000 records, so that next, previous, first and last button can be used freely and data from server can be brought as and when required.

Has anybody worked on such a thing? I am really stuck with this requirement for over 2 weeks now. Thanks to all in advance. Hope to get an answer soon on this.

Comment: I have got it working using localreader which helps me set the total, records and page count to correct values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got it working using localreader which helps me set the total, records and page count to correct values.